# How to compare 2 rows from same table (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table `Doc` data is something like this:

```
id |  name | created_dt | version
-----------------------------------------
1   doc1    2018-12-26      1
2   doc2    2018-12-26      A
3   doc1    2019-01-26      2
4   doc1    2019-02-20      3
5   doc2    2019-02-16      B
6   doc3    2019-03-20      1
5   doc2    2019-04-26      C
```

Any good way to achieve this output?

```
name | version |    days
---------------------------------
doc1       2            30
doc1       3            21
doc2       B            60
doc2       C            45
```

Query like this below

```
select name, version, datediff(dd, a.created_dt, b.created_dt)
from doc a
inner join doc b on a.name = b.name and a.id > b.id
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to get here? Why aren't the 1st versions in the results?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do if the query you give is wrong

Comment: it this excluding the original version and getting the number of days in between the subsequent version?

Comment: Your date math is a bit off in your example above.

Comment: doing a math days b/w each version created date. I'm more interested on logic of query. the query I had is wrong that I know but how to correct is what I'm looking for...

Comment: Are you sure `datediff(a.created_dt, b.created_dt)` run?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want to get the days between the current and previous version of a document omitting the first version.

You can do so using `lag()` to get the date of the previous version per document and `datediff()` to calculate the difference in days. With `row_number()` you can number the versions per document and filter the first one out.

```
SELECT name,
       version,
       days
       FROM (SELECT name,
                    version,
                    datediff(day,
                             lag(created_dt) OVER (PARTITION BY name
                                                   ORDER BY version),
                             created_dt) days,
                    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY name
                                       ORDER BY version) rn
                    FROM elbat) x
       WHERE rn <> 1
       ORDER BY name,
                version;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=06ddf691db18ccdf962a0340eb4812a7)

But I see your numbers are off. I don't know, I might have gotten this wrong or you made a mistake with your date arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the LAG() function to look back to the last created_dt partitioned by name and ordered chronologically.

```
DECLARE @doc TABLE(id INT, name NVARCHAR(50),created_dt DATETIME,version NVARCHAR(50))
INSERT @doc VALUES
(1,'doc1','12/26/2018','1'),
(2,'doc2','12/26/2018','A'),
(3,'doc1','01/26/2019','2'),
(4,'doc1','02/20/2019','3'),
(5,'doc2','02/16/2019','B'),
(6,'doc3','03/20/2019','1'),
(5,'doc2','04/26/2019','C')

SELECT
    name,
    version,
    days = DATEDIFF(DAY,PreviousDate,created_dt)
FROM
(
    SELECT
        name,
        version,
        created_dt,
        PreviousDate = LAG(created_dt) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY created_dt)
    FROM
        @doc
)AS X
WHERE
    NOT PreviousDate IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want days between two versions, here is your SQL where a row compares with the same name but prior version:

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE (id INT,  name VARCHAR(10), created_dt DATE, version VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @MyTable
(Id, name, created_dt, version)
VALUES
(1, 'doc1',  '2018-12-26', '1'),
(2, 'doc2',  '2018-12-26', 'A'),
(3, 'doc1',  '2019-01-26', '2'),
(4, 'doc1',  '2019-02-20', '3'),
(5, 'doc2',  '2019-02-16', 'B'),
(6, 'doc3',  '2019-03-20', '1'),
(5, 'doc2',  '2019-04-26', 'C')

SELECT * FROM @MyTable ORDER BY name

SELECT T1.name, T1.version, T1.created_dt CreatedT1, T2.created_dt CreatedT2, DATEDIFF(DAY, T2.created_dt, T1.created_dt) diff FROM @MyTable T1
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM @MyTable Tmp WHERE Tmp.name = T1.name AND Tmp.created_dt < T1.created_dt ORDER BY Tmp.created_dt) T2
    ORDER BY T1.id
```

The result I'm getting a bit different though (in days):

```
name    version CreatedT1   CreatedT2   diff
doc1    2   2019-01-26  2018-12-26  31
doc1    3   2019-02-20  2018-12-26  56
doc2    B   2019-02-16  2018-12-26  52
doc2    C   2019-04-26  2018-12-26  121
```